# Mocha JS: How to reference members from asynch before function in describe/it test functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js, bdd

I'm trying to dynamically load settings **asynchronously** from config files **before** running a test suite.
The test suite needs to take a config object to test, and create a server connection from it **beforeEach** test - then close the server connection **afterEach** test.
I have the following code outline, but the test suite (nested **describe**) is always called **before** the setup (**before**) function has finished; which means that the **testConfigs** array is always empty.
Is what I'm trying to do achievable, or will I have to fundamentally change the test?

```
describe('test server configs', function ()
{

    var testConfigs = [];

    before('get server configurations', function (done) {
        var conf = path.resolve('conf');
        fs.readdir(conf, function (err, files) {
                files.forEach(function (file) {
                    var config = require(path.join(conf, file));
                    testConfigs.push(config);
                });
            }

            console.dir(testConfigs); //prints the non-empty array
            done(err);
        });
    });

    describe('server test suite', function () {

        if (testConfigs.length == 0) {
            it('No server configurations to test!'); //0 tests passed, 1 pending
        }
        else {
            testConfigs.forEach(function (config) { //testConfigs is empty here
                var connection;

                beforeEach('connect to the server', function (done) {
                    connection = ServerConnection(config);
                    done();
                });

                it('should do something with the remote server', function (done) {
                    //test something with the 'connection' object
                    expect(connection.doSomething).withArgs('just a test', done).not.to.throwError();
                });

                afterEach('close connection', function (done) {
                    connection.close(done);
                });

            });
        }
    });

});
```

results:

```
      test server configs
[ [ 'local-config.json',
    { host: 'localhost',
      user: 'username',
      pass: 'password',
      path: '/' } ],
  [ 'foo.com-config.json',
    { host: 'foo.com',
      user: 'foo',
      pass: 'bar',
      path: '/boo/far' } ] ]
    server test suite
      - No server configurations to test!


  0 passing (25ms)
  1 pending
```

Comment: As a quick fix you could just use `fs.readdirSync()` (I don't think it's possible in an async way but haven't investigated it myself).

Comment: Urgh! I was hoping there would be something a little more elegant than having to resort to synchronous operations.In this case it should be fine, but what about when no synchronous functions are available!? I mean isn't that the point in the before[Each]/after[Each] utilities

Answer (score 1):

You can add new tests when test run already has been started. If you want to dynamically generate test cases, you should do it before test start.
You can use synchronous methods to read configs before tests

```
var testConfigs = []
var conf = path.resolve('conf');
var files = fs.readdirSync(conf);
files.forEach(function (file) {
    var config = require(path.join(conf, file));
    testConfigs.push(config);
});

describe('server test suite', function () {
   testConfigs.forEach(function (config) {
      //describe your dynamic test cases
   });
});
```

**UPD 26.07.15**

If you can't use synchronous function for some reasons, you can run mocha programmatically when you setup has done.

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var fs = require('fs');
var mocha = new Mocha({});

var testConfigs = global.testConfigs;
fs.readdir(conf, function (err, files) {
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        var config = require(path.join(conf, file));
        testConfigs.push(config);
    });
    mocha.run();
});
```

You have to pass the `testConfigs` via global scope, because mocha loads modules with test synchronously and this config must be ready untill the moment when mocha requires your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest I was hoping for something more useful, as this doesn't really help for cases where no synchronous alternatives exist. I was hoping that there was a common paradigm for this kind of test setup... Obviously I could do all the asynchronous tasks first and then put all the actual test stuff into the final callback, but this is also ugly, and again I think there should be a better way of doing it.

Comment: Updated the answer, with example how you can defer mocha run while your config is not loaded yet

Comment: I was just going to write a solution using [`run()`](http://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite) :-) You have to run Mocha using `--delay` before that works (but you don't have to require `mocha` for it), but otherwise, it's a good solution to create tests asynchronously.